# (Proof Check) Suppose $V$ is a non empty affine variety. If the coordinate ring $\Gamma_V$ is finite dimensional then $V$ is a point.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose $\Gamma_V$ is finite dimensional. Then we know that $V$ is finite dimensional. However, since finite subsets of $\mathbb{A}_k^n$ are always algebraic then $V$ cannot be of size greater than 1 as then we can split it into the union of proper algebraic subsets. Hence, $V$ must be of size 1, that is $V$ is a point.

I don't know if this is correct. Especially the part about the finite subsets. I think it's right because every finite subset of points can correspond to the zeros of some polynomial. Would appreciate feedback!

Comment: $\Gamma_V$ is a finite dimensional $k$-vector space, so it is a zero dimensional ring. Thus $\text{dim} V=0$. Now use irreducubility.

Comment: Given any $(a_1, \cdots ,a_n) \in \mathbb{A}^n$, the ideal $(x_1-a_1, \cdots , x_n-a_n)$ is a maximal ideal in $k[x_1, \cdots ,x_n]$. Thus any point $\mathbb{A}^n$ is an algebraic set.

Comment: I see. Thank you. But is my proof in particular incorrect?

Comment: You have the right idea, but you need to write it clearly. For example, you wrote "$V$ is finite dimensional" when you clearly want to say "$V$ is a finite set of points" or in other words, "$V$ is zero dimensional." Instead of writing "$V$ can't be of size...", you can also write it formally: "let $V=\{a_1, \cdots ,a_n\}$. If $n \geq 2$, then..." (Sorry for being too critical, but I deemed that it's necessary.)

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your specific comments a lot!